# Convert an arry of object to a collapsibe node level elements in ReactJS using antd?

Tags: reactjs, recursion, antd

Below I have a array of objects. The primary thing to consider is Level and SubField. I want them to be collapsible depending on the level and subfield.

The Level attribute is the node level on which the elements are as a tree structure starting from 0 and it can be infinite. The text to display the node level is `ServiceHeaderBlockTitle`. Also to keep in mind is that, in every node level there should be the option to edit its title or add new level or delete the level. If the `IsServiceBlock` attribute is true then we ***cannot*** add a new level from that node.

For simplicity, I am attaching a link to the video describing the working example:

[Working Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aR_sMsuky54)

The structure after using the array of objects can be seen as:

```js
/*

-Level0(SubField("/")
--Level1(SubField"/1/")
--Level1(SubField"/2/")
----Level2(SubField"/2/1")
------Level3(SubField"/2/1/1")
------Level3(SubField"/2/1/2")
--------Level3(SubField"/2/1/2/1")
--Level1(SubField"/3/")
----Level2(SubField"/3/1")
----Level2(SubField"/3/2")
----Level2(SubField"/3/3")
--Level1(SubField"/4/")
----Level2(SubField"/4/1")
----Level2(SubField"/4/2")

... and so on
*/
```

Please find the data below:

```js
[
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 1,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Header",
    "SubField": "/",
    "Level": 0,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 57,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Project Administration",
    "SubField": "/1/",
    "Level": 1,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 58,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Innovation",
    "SubField": "/2/",
    "Level": 1,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 76,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Commercialization",
    "SubField": "/3/",
    "Level": 1,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 77,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Quality/Food Safety Audit",
    "SubField": "/4/",
    "Level": 1,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 78,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Co-Man sourcing",
    "SubField": "/3/1/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 79,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Co-Man Vetting",
    "SubField": "/3/2/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 80,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Line Trail",
    "SubField": "/3/3/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 81,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Gap Analysis",
    "SubField": "/4/1/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 82,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "HACCP",
    "SubField": "/4/2/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 84,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Product Development",
    "SubField": "/2/2/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 59,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Project Charter",
    "SubField": "/1/1/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 60,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Internal Ideation",
    "SubField": "/1/2/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 61,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "White Space Opportunity",
    "SubField": "/2/1/",
    "Level": 2,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 62,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Territory Mapping/Platform Design",
    "SubField": "/2/1/1/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 70,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Creative Council Session",
    "SubField": "/2/1/2/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 71,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Trends Report",
    "SubField": "/2/1/3/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 85,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Product Development Administration",
    "SubField": "/2/2/1/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 103,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Brand/Project Immersion",
    "SubField": "/1/1/1/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 10,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 104,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Project Charter Preparation",
    "SubField": "/1/1/2/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 23,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 105,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Timeline",
    "SubField": "/1/1/3/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 23,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 106,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Project Organization-Data Collection",
    "SubField": "/1/1/4/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 38,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 107,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Brand/Project Immersion",
    "SubField": "/1/2/1/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 10,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 108,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Meeting-Internal",
    "SubField": "/1/2/2/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 23,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 109,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Meeting Report",
    "SubField": "/1/2/3/",
    "Level": 3,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 26,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 110,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Brand/Project Immersion",
    "SubField": "/2/1/1/1/",
    "Level": 4,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 10,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 111,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Meeting-Internal",
    "SubField": "/2/1/1/2/",
    "Level": 4,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 10,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 115,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Creative Council Brief",
    "SubField": "/2/1/3/1/",
    "Level": 4,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 10,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 86,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Process Technology Assessment ",
    "SubField": "/2/2/1/1/",
    "Level": 4,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 87,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Analogue Cutting-Internal",
    "SubField": "/2/2/1/2/",
    "Level": 4,
    "IsServiceBlock": false,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": null,
    "IsActive": true
  },
  {
    "ServiceHeaderBlockId": 114,
    "ServiceHeaderBlockTitle": "Development Brief",
    "SubField": "/2/2/1/1/1/",
    "Level": 5,
    "IsServiceBlock": true,
    "ResourceDescriptionId": 10,
    "IsActive": true
  }
]
```